# App crashes during run-time after updating to Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I already tried Invalidating caches, cleaning the project, re-installing the app.
I'm not using data binding.

I'm using **Realm plugin** `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.3.1`

Here's some relevant info from `build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion 29.0.3

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
```

Android Gradle plugin: 3.6.0 
Gradle: 5.6.4

This is the log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/R$drawable;
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$1.<init>(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:63)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.preload(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:57)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:328)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:278)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:221)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(AppCompatActivity.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6909)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1596)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.R$drawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.develop-dkwyyr2-QVmFBqzVHNDZtQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.develop-dkwyyr2-QVmFBqzVHNDZtQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.develop-dkwyyr2-QVmFBqzVHNDZtQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$1.<init>(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:63) 
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.preload(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:57) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:328) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:278) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:221) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:543) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(AppCompatActivity.java:98) 
    at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6909) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1596) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
```

Comment: are you using databinding? I got some problems for `app:sometext=@{R.string.text}`

Comment: @kike No, I'm not using data binding.

Comment: I have the same problem. After updating android studio to version 3.6 I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are you using Realm in your project? I had the same problem and fixed it by upgrading my Realm dependency to the latest stable version because I found [this related issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6557).

On build.gradle(Project):

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2'
}
```

After that, I cleaned and rebuilt the project (just in case).

Comment: This does not provide a complete and descriptive answer. The Post doesn't state that he used Realm in project nither the stack trace said.

Comment: @KiranManiya I updated my answer to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: I don't know why but I also updated realm plugin and problem solved! whereas in the error text there wasn't any sign about realm

Comment: THANK YOU. My app suddenly started to crash on launch (same error.message. `Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/R$drawable;`), and I tried everything, but this one worked. Any idea why this works?

Comment: It works for me too, thanks a lot, it took all my weekend