# Android App runtime crash after update gradle plugin 3.6

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, runtimeexception

Android App was working with no crash, After updating the **Gradle plugin** to version **3.6** faced the runtime crash below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.package.app, PID: 9420
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/R$drawable;
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.<clinit>(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:113)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.get(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at my.package.app.abstracts.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:94)
        at my.package.app.ui.activity_splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.R$drawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package.app-ubNE5Y0S9Ec7hNJGohi9Sw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.package.app-ubNE5Y0S9Ec7hNJGohi9Sw==/lib/arm, /data/app/my.package.app-ubNE5Y0S9Ec7hNJGohi9Sw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.<clinit>(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:113) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.get(Unknown Source:0) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
        at my.package.app.abstracts.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:94) 
        at my.package.app.ui.activity_splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:48) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975) 


ext.gradlVersion = '3.6.0'
...
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradlVersion"

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First implement [multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588459/what-is-android-multidex) into your project then restart `android studio` and run your app.
If still you face this issue, then you need to downgrade your `android studio's` stable version `3.5.3`

Below `Android Studio 3.5` disable Instant run:

```
Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy --> Instant run.
```

Issue: [Click Me](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6557) , [Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393230/app-crashes-during-run-time-after-updating-to-android-studio-3-6)

Hope this mey help you

Comment: I checked out links before, in my case does not work, Instant run not available in android studio 3.6 at the above direction

Comment: May be problem whith new gradles downgrade it and check hope this may work..because this studio is not pure stable and sorry my mistake instant run removed since 3.5 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57616477/3974530

Comment: I had to downgrade Android Studio and pull the project from SVC! it still does not work after downgrading IDE

Comment: I'm finding solution!!
OK downgrade Android Studio then did you set your old gradle version?

Comment: Not sure, but I think that's the problem

Comment: For me, I didn't need to downgrade anything. If you use `realm` be sure to update it to the last version. It's incompatible with gradle plugin version `3.6.0`.

Answer (score 1):

First Take a backup of your project after Migrate your project in `AndroidX`

1. Goto Toolbar  into Refactor
2. Goto bottom option and select to Migrate to androidX

And migrate it. Check if the error still happens.

Comment: Not works in my case